# Programmatically Create+Mount Disk From Within Google Compute VM

Tags: google-compute-engine, mount-point

I'd like to write a script that can be run from a Google Compute instance, which creates a disk and mounts it. The disks I've created and mounted so far have been done through the web console. The problem I'm having is in figuring out the paramaters for [`safe_format_and_mount`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks) (and possibly in some step before).

From within the instance, here is my attempt so far:

```
ami@snowflake:~$ gcloud compute disks create foo --zone europe-west1-c
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/snowflake-    1056/zones/europe-west1-c/disks/foo].
NAME ZONE           SIZE_GB TYPE        STATUS
foo  europe-west1-c 500     pd-standard READY
ami@snowflake:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    10G  0 disk 
`-sda1   8:1    0    10G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   500G  0 disk /mnt/work
sdc      8:32   0     2T  0 disk /mnt/data1
```

The [`docs for safe_format_and_mount`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks) give now this sequence:

```
$ sudo mkdir MOUNT_POINT
$ sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" DISK_LOCATION MOUNT_POINT
```

However, I have no idea what `DISK_LOCATION` is, nor does `lsblock`'s output give anything that seems pertinent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that you need to attach the disk to your instance before you can use it:

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk myinstance --disk foo \
    --zone europe-west1-c --device-name foo
```

The `--device-name` option allows you to specify the device name the guest operating system will see. If you use the same name as the disk name, the disk location will be `/dev/disk/by-id/google-foo`.